# AdMob banner in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, admob

so I have made an app and now Im putting ad banners here. I followed this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start and everything works fine but I want to put banners to my fragments too. I was looking here on website and I found this to put to fragment

```
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but when i click on fragment afterwards the app stop working

Im total beginner in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put bellow code in xml layout file

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

> Where banner_ad_unit_id is your ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx
>
> To crate ad unit id follow bellow link
>   https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638

Add dependancy in build.gradle file

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'

Now to display Ads write bellow code in Activity

```
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: thanks, and last question: should i create new banner for every single fragment or still using the same one for all

Comment: You can use same for all , no need to create new one , means if you want to show ads in another fragment then you have to add new Adview for that fragment but the ad unit id will be the same